# make PDO from string

Tags: php, pdo

I'm in the process of procedurally making a PDO statement, so far i've got

```
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $values_array = array();
    foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value){
        $sql .= $key;
        $sql .= " = :".$key.", ";
        $values_array[':'.$key] = $value;
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
    $sql .= " WHERE id = :id";
    $values_array[':id'] = $user_id;

    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    print_r($non_empty_fields);
    print_r($values_array);
    echo($sql);
    $sth -> execute($values_array);
    $num_affected_rows = $sth -> affected_rows;
    $sth -> close();
```

and when i run it, i get

```
 Array
(
    [gender] => female
    [device_id] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
)
Array
(
    [:gender] => female
    [:device_id] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
    [:id] => 35
)
UPDATE users SET gender = :gender, device_id = :device_id WHERE id = :id<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in <b>/Sites/api/include/DbHandler.php</b> on line <b>280</b><br />
```

I suspect its because I'm not setting the prepared statement properly, so my question is: how do you make a prepared statement from a string?

UPDATE:

call_user_func so the code now looks like:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $values_array = array();
    foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value){
        $sql .= $key;
        $sql .= " = ?, ";
        $values_array[] = &$value;
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
    $sql .= " WHERE id = ?";
    $values_array[] = &$user_id;

    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = array_merge(array(str_repeat('s', count($values_array))), array_values($values_array));
    call_user_func_array(array(&$sth, 'bind_param'), $params);
    $sth -> execute();
```

now the error I'm getting isn't represented, pdo just doesn't update the table.

Comment: Although your process is a little complex, your final statement seems to be alright. Has `$this->conn` been initialized properly? Also you should check for `$this->conn->errorInfo();` after `prepare()` call

Comment: If that `<br />` is actually part of the query you generated, prepare will fail, as that's not valid SQL. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-returnvalues

Comment: @TiesonT. its not a part of it. Thanks for the resource tho

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I added the call to error info after the prepare and got this error:  `Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()`  . `$this->conn` worked for Inserting a new user, and i initialized it in the same way, idk why it may have broken this time around

Comment: I haven't used MySQLi myself, but if I'm not mistaken - a placeholder such as `:gender` is for use with PDO. MySQLi uses `?` placeholders for parameters. Could that be the cause of the problem? SQL looks fine. But for use with PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh `Mysqli`? i thought you said it was PDO. Mysqli doesnt support named markers like `:id`, you have to use question marks like `?`

> This parameter can include one or more parameter markers in the SQL statement by embedding question mark (?) characters at the appropriate positions.

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**

And for PDO you can use either

> Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the
>   PDOStatement::execute() method. The SQL statement can contain zero or
>   more named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers for which
>   real values will be substituted when the statement is executed. You
>   cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the
>   same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style. Use these
>   parameters to bind any user-input, do not include the user-input
>   directly in the query.

**[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)**

Comment: soory for the confusion, i was actually confused as well haha i didn't know mysqli's prepared statement didn't mean pdo